# How to get CRT of allocated std::String?

Tags: c++, dll, msvcrt

I have static lib provided by 3rd party which is to be integrated with my C++ (Visual Studio 120 ToolSet) project which is a dll. Then this dll is used in my application.

```
  //dll side
    class Foo
    {
     // m_name is set from the value returned from 3rd party lib.
     //  m_name = [object in static lib].getName();

     std::string getName()
       { 
       return m_name;
       }
    }

  //application side
   void main()
    {
     Foo* f = new Foo();
     f->getName();// application crashes when deallocating string
    }
```

Crash is occurred when destructing std::string. I suspect that the string returned from 3rd party library is allocated in different C++ run time. How to find the allocation CRT of that 3rd party lib string?

Comment: Mixing different compiler implementations in C++ always is problematic. Even if you manage to fix the current problem, there might be quite a bunch of others just waiting for a chance to bite you... Try to get the appropriate version of the library for your tools, if there is none, try to get the sources to compile it yourself. You might ask for support at the vendor's directly, too.

Comment: @Aconcagua 
True that. But they send as binaries and it is placed in a directory as VS2013 (According to a convention). If there is a way to find the allocator pro grammatically I would be able to ask for fix at their end.

Comment: 12.0 tools - and VS2013? Should be the [same](https://omwtm.blog/2014/12/03/visual-studio-2013-version-numbers-and-updates/)... Are you sure that you don't possibly have totally different issue? Have you debugged?

Comment: @Aconcagua 
Yp. I have built everything with previous release of that 3rd party library and everything worked perfectly. With latest update only the static lib has been updated, not even a single modification in their headers. 
If there is a way to get string allocator runtime version that would be helpful.After debugging I found out that the string is destructed in CRT 120, but couldn't find a way to get allocation runtime.

Comment: Although I'd rather expect that already compilation fails then - they haven't by accident switched from 32 to 64 bit build?